# iOS Deep Linking not working when viewed through UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, uiwebview, deep-linking

I have a mobile website that contains a deep link into my app, and this works in Safari and Chrome on iOS. However, users who arrive at the mobile website via QR readers are often looking at it through the QR reader's webview rather than Safari or Chrome. The deep link does not seem to work in the webview.  Also, I have no control over the QR reader app itself, obviously.

Example (uses Youtube's deep linking): https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1467/

QR code to the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNWJj.png

In the example, neither `direct deeplink` nor `javascript redirection to deeplink` work inside the webview, but all three links work in Safari and Chrome.

Is there any way to force the embedded webview to open Safari or follow the deeplink?

Comment: I would suggest creating small test App with WebView and trying to tap on your Universal Links from this App. This will give you hint is WebView support Universal Links at all. I did not tried this so can't say.